# How to completely remove ruby?

Tags: ruby, linux, rvm

I have installed multiple versions of Ruby that causes some problems. How do I remove it completey(all versions)?
I use Linux(Fedora)

Comment: @SenthilKumar I had the rvm installed. I typed rvm remove all, but ruby packages still exist

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `rvm implode` to get rid of RVM installed Rubies and `yum` for uninstalling distriubtion packages if there are any.

From the RVM docs:

> implode   - removes all ruby installations it manages, everything in
>   ~/.rvm

Comment: And once again one wonders what the downvote was for...

Comment: You gave instructions how to remove RVM, missing rubies is only side effect of you command.

Comment: I personally use `rbenv`, but the part "removes all ruby installations it manages" from the official docs sounded like what OP wanted to me.

Comment: your answer is even more wrong, it shows only how to remove everything but `rbenv` ... and continuing there is more ruby managers => https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/blob/master/help/alt.md

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I tried to say. Anyway, from your profile I see you are an RVM developer, so you may take this more personally than is necessary.

Comment: of course I do, but still the question was how to remove rubies not RVM, someone might want to continue using RVM (even it was not intention in the initial question).

Answer (score 5):

As suggested, you can use `rvm implode` which removes ruby,

Also find ruby:

```
whereis ruby
```

and then remove each one of them like:

```
rm -f /usr/local/bin/ruby
```

Then check the file `.installed.list` in the build directory to check list of installed files. Also you can remove and confirm that ruby files are removed

Answer (score 1):

It's a trick but should work to uninstall all rubies without removing RVM:

```
rvm uninstall --gems $(rvm list strings | tr "\n" ',')
rvm cleanup all
```